# How to know when a thread has completed its task

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

As I am using gui and I need to create a thread to complete a task. See I want to display a dialog letting the user know the task has been completed I have tried

```
if(!thread.isAlive()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
}
```

But that doesnt work.

Can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: you want your main thread to wait for another thread to finish?

Comment: Have the thread tell you, or have it show the dialog itself. Don't put code like this into the event thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do your work using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Override the `done()` method and have it notify your GUI that work is complete.

A simple example that nearly matches your use case is shown in the Javadocs at the top of the page:

```
final JLabel label;
class MeaningOfLifeFinder extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
  @Override
  public String doInBackground() {
    // Here you do the work of your thread
    return findTheMeaningOfLife();
  }

  @Override
  protected void done() {
    // Here you notify the GUI
    try {
      label.setText(get());
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the thread print a message as it's last line of code in it's run method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      //whatever you want this thread to do

      //as the last line of code = the thread is going to terminate
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done"); 
  }
}
thread.start();
```

If you want the main thread to wait for the thread to finish, in the main thread's code you'd use:

```
thread.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a listener in your main Thread, and then program  your Thread to tell the listener that it has completed.

```
public interface ThreadCompleteListener {
    void notifyOfThreadComplete(final Thread thread);
}
```

then create the following class:

```
public abstract class NotifyingThread extends Thread {
  private final Set<ThreadCompleteListener> listeners
                   = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ThreadCompleteListener>();
  public final void addListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
  public final void removeListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }
  private final void notifyListeners() {
    for (ThreadCompleteListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.notifyOfThreadComplete(this);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public final void run() {
    try {
      doRun();
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
  public abstract void doRun();
}

NotifyingThread thread1 = new OneOfYourThreads();
thread1.addListener(this); // add ourselves as a listener
thread1.start();           // Start the Thread
```

then, as each Thread exits, your `notifyOfThreadComplete` method will be invoked with the Thread instance that just completed. So now you can run any of your code in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Callable` thread. It will return value,So we can identify that it completed its task.